# HtmlAgiltyPack parse HTML and take value out of span tag and class name

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML that I download via my webrequest client. And out of entire html I want to parse only this part of HTML:

```
<span class="sku">
<span class="fb">SKU                            :</span>118880101
</span>
```

I'm using HTML agilty pack to retrieve this value: 118880101

And I've written something like this:

```
 HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
 htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
 return htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='sku']").ElementAt(0).InnerText;
```

And this returns me this value from HTML:

```
SKU                            :118880101
```

Literally like this, spaces included... How can I fix this logic with HTML Agilty pack so that I can only take out this 118880101 value?

Can someone help me out?

Edit: a regex like this would do the thing:

```
Substring(skuRaw.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

which would mean to take everything after ":' sign in string that I receive... But I'm not sure if it's safe to use regex like this ?

Comment: have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
     HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
     htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
     var innerText=htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='sku']")
                          .ElementAt(0).InnerText;
     return innerText.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

if you want to use only Html Agility pack try this

```
       var child = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='fb']")
                           .FirstOrDefault();
        if (child != null)
        {
            var parent = child.ParentNode;
            parent.RemoveChild(child);
            var innerText = parent.InnerText;              
        }
```